# handling encoded elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

My xslt transform does not pick up my document, this is because some/most elements are encoded,

e.g. my document:

```
<Template>
  <ID>14</ID>
  <Name>name of report</Name>
  <VersionNumber>1.0</VersionNumber>
  <CoverPage>
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;h3 style="text-align: center;"&gt;
&lt;br class="GENTICS_ephemera" /&gt;
&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;h3 style="text-align: center;"&gt;
&lt;br class="GENTICS_ephemera" /&gt;
&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;h3 style="text-align: center;"&gt;Property Valuation Report&lt;/h3&gt;  
  </CoverPage>
</Template>
```

This will never work:

```
  <xsl:template match="span">
    <fo:inline>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="br">
    <fo:block>
      <fo:leader />
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
```

Question: How can I get my document in the corrent format (technically my xml is valid and in correct format) but I want to do an xsl transform so I need to be able to pick up the correct tags

Here is the method for my transform:

```
    private static MemoryStream Transform(XNode xmlData, XNode xslt)
    {
        XmlWriter writer = null;
        var xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
        try
        {
            //load the xsl
            xslTrans.Load(xslt.CreateReader());

            //create the output stream
            var result = new MemoryStream();
            writer = XmlWriter.Create(result, null);

            //create the xml reader for the data
            var data = xmlData.CreateReader();

            //do the actual transform of xml
            xslTrans.Transform(data, null, writer);

            writer.Close();
            return new MemoryStream(result.ToArray());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var errors = XslErrors.GetCompileErrors(xslTrans);
            if (errors == null)
            {
                // Failed to obtain list of compile errors
                throw;
            }

            if (writer != null) writer.Close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

*Update* My XSLT Doc...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="2.0"
                xmlns:fp="http://example.com/fp"
                exclude-result-prefixes="fp">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"  />
  <xsl:variable name="pagewidth" select="21.5"/>
  <xsl:variable name="bodywidth" select="17"/>
  <xsl:template match="Template">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt" color="black">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="Cover" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="BodyContent" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">
          <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm"/>
          <!-- Header -->
          <fo:region-before margin-bottom="2cm" extent="5cm" padding="0cm" border-width="0cm"/>
          <!-- Footer -->
          <fo:region-after margin-top="2cm" extent="2cm" padding="0cm" border-width="0cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>

      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Cover">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" >
          <fo:block id="CoverPageWrapper">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fp:ParseFragment(.)/node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CoverPage" />
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>

      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="BodyContent" initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
          <fo:table margin-left="2cm" padding-top="1cm" table-layout="fixed" width="170mm">
            <fo:table-column column-width="70mm" />
            <fo:table-column column-width="100mm" />
            <fo:table-body>
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding-start="1pt" padding-end="1pt" padding-before="1pt" padding-after="1pt" padding-top="1pt" padding-bottom="1pt">
                  <fo:block-container width="3cm" height="2cm">
                    <fo:block>

                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:block-container>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding-start="1pt" padding-end="1pt" padding-before="1pt" padding-after="1pt" padding-top="1pt" padding-bottom="1pt">
                  <fo:block-container width="4cm" height="2.2cm">
                    <fo:block>

                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:block-container>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
          <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="8pt" padding-top="0.5cm">
            Page
            <fo:page-number/>
            of
            <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="FinalPage"/>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block id="BodyContentWrapper">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Body" />
          </fo:block>
          <!-- End of the document stuff that is needed-->
          <fo:block id="FinalPage"/>

        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="label[@data-field-class='ui-templatefield']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@fo-checkbox" >
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="text()='True'">
            <fo:inline font-size="9pt" color="black">
              [
              <fo:inline font-family="ZapfDingbats" border-color="black" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" font-size="6pt">&#x2715;</fo:inline>
              ]
            </fo:inline>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:inline>
              [&#160;&#160;&#160;]
              <!-->fo:inline font-family="ZapfDingbats" font-size="10pt">&#x274F;</fo:inline-->
            </fo:inline>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <fo:inline>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
        </fo:inline>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span">
    <fo:inline>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="blockquote">
    <fo:block
      space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt"
      start-indent="1em" end-indent="1em">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h1">
    <fo:block font-size="22pt">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <fo:block font-size="18pt">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h3">
    <fo:block font-size="16pt">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h4">
    <fo:block font-size="14pt">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h5">
    <fo:block font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h6">
    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize-style">
    <xsl:param name="pString" select="string(@style)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($pString)"/>
      <xsl:when test="contains($pString,';')">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style">
          <xsl:with-param name="pString"
               select="substring-before($pString,';')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style">
          <xsl:with-param name="pString"
               select="substring-after($pString,';')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="{normalize-space(substring-before($pString,':'))}">
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after($pString,':'))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:if test="@class='bordered'">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-width">1pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p" >
    <fo:block space-before="4pt" space-after="4pt">
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ol">
    <fo:list-block start-indent="1cm" space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:list-block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ol/li">
    <fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../@type != ''">
              <xsl:number format="{../@type}"/>.
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:number format="1"/>.
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-label>
      <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
        <fo:block font-size="11pt" color="black" font-family="Arial, Verdana, sans-serif">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul">
    <fo:list-block start-indent="1cm" space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:list-block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul/li">
    <fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="../@type ='disc'">
            <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="../@type='square'">
            <fo:block font-family="ZapfDingbats">n</fo:block>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="../@type='circle'">
            <fo:block font-family="ZapfDingbats">m</fo:block>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="count(ancestor::ul) = 1">
                <fo:block>&#x2022;</fo:block>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="count(ancestor::ul) = 2">
                <fo:block font-family="ZapfDingbats">m</fo:block>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:block font-family="ZapfDingbats">n</fo:block>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </fo:list-item-label>
      <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dl">
    <fo:block space-before="6pt" space-after="6pt">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dt">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dd">
    <fo:block start-indent="5mm">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <fo:table>
      <xsl:attribute name="width">
        <xsl:text>170mm</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="caption">
    <fo:caption>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:caption>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="colgroup">
    <xsl:for-each select="col">
      <fo:table-column>
        <xsl:attribute name="column-width">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@width, '%')">
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="floor(number(translate(@width,'%','')) div 100 * $bodywidth)"/>
              <xsl:text>cm</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="floor(@width div 72)"/>
              <xsl:text>in</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </fo:table-column>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tbody">
    <fo:table-body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:table-body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <fo:table-row>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="th">
    <fo:table-cell font-weight="bold" text-align="center">
      <xsl:if test="ancestor::table/@border > 0">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-width">0.1mm</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td">
    <fo:table-cell  padding-start="1pt" padding-end="1pt" padding-before="1pt" padding-after="1pt" padding-top="1pt" padding-bottom="1pt">
      <xsl:if test="ancestor::table/@border > 0">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-width">0.1mm</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="ancestor::tr/@class='titleformat'">
        <xsl:attribute name="background-color">black</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="color">white</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tt">
    <fo:inline font-family="monospace">
      <xsl:apply-templates  select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="img">
    <fo:external-graphic>
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        file:<xsl:value-of
        select="@src"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="width">
        <xsl:value-of
        select="@width"/>px
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="height">
        <xsl:value-of
        select="@height"/>px
      </xsl:attribute>
    </fo:external-graphic>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pre">
    <fo:block white-space-collapse="false">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <fo:inline>
      <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="i">
    <fo:inline>
      <xsl:attribute name="font-style">italic</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:inline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hr">
    <xsl:if test="@class='ui-pagebreak'">
      <fo:block break-after="page" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="@class=''">
      <fo:block>
        <fo:leader
          leader-pattern="rule" leader-length.optimum="100%"
          rule-style="double" rule-thickness="1pt"/>
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="br">
    <fo:block>
      <fo:leader />
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use with .NET and C#? If it is XslCompiledTransform you could use an extension object or function parsing the content of the `CoverPage` element into nodes, then you could process the nodes with templates.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - updated my answer, its xslcompiledtransform

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c# .net XSLT -" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: The answer, of course, is that the string you have isn't markup -- it needs to be first parsed -- outside of XSLT -- into an XML document and then you can apply a transformation on this XML document. THis isn't possible to do in pure XSLT 1.0 or pure XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 3.0 (still in working draft) one can call the standard function `parse-xml()` to do the parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with XslCompiledTransform and an extension object:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
        proc.Load("../../XSLTFile1.xslt");

        XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
        xsltArgs.AddExtensionObject("http://example.com/fp", new FragmentParser());

        proc.Transform("../../XMLFile1.xml", xsltArgs, Console.Out);
    }
}

public class FragmentParser
{
    public IXPathNavigable ParseFragment(string fragment)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocumentFragment frag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
        frag.InnerXml = fragment;
        return frag;
    }
}
```

then in your stylesheet you can use code as the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fp="http://example.com/fp"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fp"
>
  <xsl:template match="CoverPage">
    <Test>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fp:ParseFragment(.)/node()"/>
    </Test>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h3">
    <heading>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </heading>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
In your stylesheet you can change

```
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Cover">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" >
      <fo:block id="CoverPageWrapper">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fp:ParseFragment(.)/node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CoverPage" />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
```

to

```
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Cover">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" >
      <fo:block id="CoverPageWrapper">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fp:ParseFragment(CoverPage)/node()"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
```

Or add a template for CoverPage e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="CoverPage">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="fp:ParseFragment(.)/node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then above you would simply do e.g.

```
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Cover">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" >
      <fo:block id="CoverPageWrapper">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CoverPage" />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/tf741884%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for a documentation of using extension objects with XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: I have checked your code and it seems to work, however I am not sure where to actually put '<xsl:apply-templates select="fp:ParseFragment(.)/node()"/>' This code should only ever run once? At the start? (trying to find out where it fits inside my xsl:fo document)

Comment: As my sample shows, it belongs into any template of elements containing escaped markup. In the input sample you posted that is a `CoverPage` element so you would write a template with `match="CoverPage"` and then you can call the extension object method to parse the contents of the `CoverPage` element inside that template, as my sample shows. Of course elsewhere you need to ensure that the `CoverPage` elements are processed but your posted XSLT sample does not relate to the input XML sample you posted so it is hard to give more precise advice.

Comment: i have added my xslt - just want to be clear I understand, I added where I felt the code should go but it did not work - I actually get the template coming out correct, then I get the xml coming out for some reason